# Need Help Loading Dat-GUI with Meteor.js

Tags: javascript, user-interface, meteor, requirejs, dat.gui

I am trying to load Dat-GUI : https://github.com/dataarts/dat.gui
with my meteor project. I added the dat-GUI source in the client/lib folder. 
Here is my code:

```
Template.EditorControllbar.rendered = function () {
    var controllBar = document.getElementById('controllbar'),
        gui, folder, controller;

    // Create GUI
    gui = new dat.GUI({autoPlace:false});
    controllBar.appendChild(gui.domElement);

    // Create folders
    var renderFolder = gui.addFolder('Render'),
    meshFolder = gui.addFolder('Mesh'),
    lightFolder = gui.addFolder('Light'),
    exportFolder = gui.addFolder('Export');

};
```

When I run the server I get the following error:

```
Exception from Deps afterFlush function function: ReferenceError: dat is not defined
    at Object.Template.EditorControllbar.rendered (http://localhost:3000/client/views/toons/toon_edit/editor_controllbar/editor_controllbar.js?5613eb3f7dfe2c5aed33925dfe2970dcc11a04b4:33:15)
    at http://localhost:3000/packages/ui.js?9419ac08328918a04e7a49464a988d45f851e1b0:439:23
    at _assign.flush (http://localhost:3000/packages/deps.js?4a82362ae66e863a1c1a8b0a5fec6f665e2038d1:348:13) debug.js:4
```

The same code works on codepen though:
http://codepen.io/praneybehl/pen/DabKv

Does anyone know how can I load Dat-GUI with Meteor.
Any help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance,
Praney

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You added the file https://github.com/dataarts/dat.gui/blob/master/build/dat.gui.min.js in `client/lib`? Meteor will wrap all js-files in a function, so `var`-variables in js-files won't be visible in other files, so you can't use the `dat` variable if you add the file this way. Instead, you need to add the file in the `client/compatibility` folder. js-files in this folder won't be wrapped in a function, so the var variable will be a global variable, and you can use it in other files.

Comment: Can't believe I forgot that, I guess I could use some sleep. Thanks mate :)